# How to echo data from specific table using php

Tags: php

I have an sql statement that has left join between table **orders** and **order_item**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN order_item on orders.order_id = order_item.order_id 
LEFT JOIN product on order_item.product_id = product.product_id 
LEFT JOIN categories on categories.categories_id = product.categories_id 
LEFT JOIN brands on brands.brand_id = product.brand_id 
WHERE order_date >= '$start_date' AND order_date <= '$end_date' and order_status = 1";

$query = $connect->query($sql);
```

I echo `$row['quantity']`

But it's displaying quantity from table **orders** and not from table
**order_item**.

How can I echo quantity from **order_item**?

Answer (score 2):

You should add the `quantity` field from `order_item` into the `SELECT`. Also, you should use a [Column Alias](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/), in order to prevent duplicated column names issues.

This query should do the job:

```
$sql = "SELECT orders.*, order_item.quantity AS item_quantity FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN order_item on orders.order_id = order_item.order_id 
LEFT JOIN product on order_item.product_id = product.product_id 
LEFT JOIN categories on categories.categories_id = product.categories_id 
LEFT JOIN brands on brands.brand_id = product.brand_id 
WHERE order_date >= '$start_date' AND order_date <= '$end_date' and order_status = 1";
```

As we are using an alias, you must change the following:
`$row['quantity']` -> `$row['item_quantity']`